# Argument 'AppCtrl' is not a function, got undefined, can't seem to fix

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

This is my angularApp.js:

```
var app = angular.module('intuo', ['ui.router','ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url : '/home',
        templateUrl : '/home.html',
        controller : 'MainCtrl'
    }).state('login', {
        url : '/login',
        templateUrl : '/login.html',
        controller : 'AuthCtrl',
        onEnter : ['$state', 'auth',
        function($state, auth) {
            if (auth.isLoggedIn()) {
                $state.go('home');
            }
        }]
    }).state('register', {
        url : '/register',
        templateUrl : '/register.html',
        controller : 'AuthCtrl',
        onEnter : ['$state', 'auth',
        function($state, auth) {
            if (auth.isLoggedIn()) {
                $state.go('home');
            }
        }]
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}]);
```

This is my bootstrap.js file (basically just create new module):

```
angular.module('controllers', []);
```

This is my AppCtrl.js:

```
angular.module('controllers')
    .controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdSidenav', 
        function($scope, $mdSidenav){
            $scope.toggleSidenav = function(menuId) {
              $mdSidenav(menuId).toggle();
            };
        }
    ]);
```

Example of other controller i have (probably will get me the same error):

```
angular.module('controllers')
    .controller('NavCtrl', ['$scope', 'auth',
        function($scope, auth) {
            $scope.isLoggedIn = auth.isLoggedIn;
            $scope.currentUser = auth.currentUser;
            $scope.logOut = auth.logOut;
        }
    ]);
```

This is my index.html file where it says AppCtrl & NavCtrl:

```
<body layout="column" ng-controller="AppCtrl">


  <md-toolbar layout="row">
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
      <md-button ng-click="toggleSidenav('left')" hide-gt-sm class="md-icon-button">
        <md-icon aria-label="Menu" md-icon="../images/menu.svg"></md-icon>
      </md-button>
      <a href="/#/">Intuo App</a>

    </div>
  </md-toolbar>
  <div layout="row" flex>
    <md-sidenav layout="column" class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')">
         <!-- <nav class="navbar navbar-default pull-right" >-->
              <ul  ng-controller="NavCtrl">
                <li ng-show="isLoggedIn()"><a>{{ currentUser() }}</a></li>
                <li ng-show="isLoggedIn()"><a href="" ng-click="logOut()">Log Out</a></li>
                <li ng-hide="isLoggedIn()"><a href="/#/login">Log In</a></li>
                <li ng-hide="isLoggedIn()"><a href="/#/register">Register</a></li>
              </ul>
          <!--  </nav>-->

    </md-sidenav>
    <div layout="column" flex id="content">
      <md-content layout="column" flex class="md-padding">
            <ui-view></ui-view>
      </md-content>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The error i'm getting is : 
Error: ng:areq
Bad Argument

Argument 'AppCtrl' is not a function, got undefined.

I've looked around a bit but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Have you included all the scripts on the page?

Comment: ... *sigh* yeah that's right. I forgot. Anyway it works now thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Your both the controller's belongs to `controllers` module & basically you are initializing angular on the page by having `ng-app="intuo"` which has `intuo` module. But `intuo` don't have  `controllers` module included in it(So controller is unreachable to your `intuo` module & that why angular is throwing an error.). You should include `Controller` module to your main module `intuo`.

**Code**

```
//initialize controller module first before intializing
angular.module('controllers', []);
var app = angular.module('intuo', ['ui.router','ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate', 'controllers']);
```

Comment: Ah yes this seems obvious. Now i got it like this: 
`angular.module('controllers', []);
angular.module('factories', []);

var app = angular.module('intuo', ['ui.router','ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate', 'controllers', 'factories']);`

I'm still getting the same error :o

Comment: @Jepix that's amazing..keep module initialization in separate JS would be great idea.. :)

Comment: Ok, i've made 2 new files Controllers.js & Factories.js, with `angular.module('controllers', []);` && `angular.module('factories', []);`.

My angularApp.js file now looks like it should: `var app = angular.module('intuo', ['ui.router','ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate', 'controllers', 'factories']);` 

Now i'm getting the error "Module 'controllers' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument." I must still be missing something.

Comment: @Jepix see if you want to register module with dependencies then make sure that the module you are going to add in dependency array `[]` should be initialize before injecting into `[]`, could you double check that..service & controller are loaded before the `var app = angular.module('intuo', ['ui.router','ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate', 'controllers', 'factories']);` this code gets executed

Comment: Ah man sorry but i'm retarded, i forgot to include the files in my html... i should tattoo it on my arm because every time i can't seem to find a solution for a problem it's because i forget to initialize the files in my html <.< thanks anyway buddy!

Answer (score 0):

Always to remember to include the correct scripts loading in each file! Forgetting to load in the controllers & factories will get you errors!